# I have a query about Loops in JS. I am a newbie

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS, noticed this while practising Loops

If this code:

```
let i = 0;
while ( i<=5 ) {
  console.log (i);
  i++;
}
```

is written like this

```
let i = 0;
while ( i<=5 ) {
  console.log (i);
}
i++;
```

it becomes an infinite loop, can some one please explain how placing the increment outside the curly braces changes the behaviour of the code?

Comment: The braces define what happens in each loop

Comment: U can think the app run from top to bottom. first line you declare `I` in second line you start looping with `while` in third line you console `I` in fourth line you end the loop. So since it is a loop if `the condition is not satisfied the app will go back` to line 2. which will not end because you are not increasing the `I`. The app will not reach to the line `5` because it always going back to line 2

Comment: Make sure to read the official documentation: [`while`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Answer (score 3):

Placing `i++` outside the curly braces causes it to be outside the loop. If the increment is outside the loop, the value of `i` never gets changed inside the loop, so the loop would always continue executing since the value of `i` remains 0 after every iteration of the loop and `i<=5` always evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces represent everything that will be executed while the condition is true. When you place the `i++` outside the curly brace, you have placed it outside the loop. Only once the condition (`i<=5`) is false do you move on to the next line after the curly braces.